# Angular 5 and Primeng dropdown add and remove option dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I work on angular 5 and primeng. My project page has 2 `p-dropdown`'s and requirment is, if the label in `car dropdown` is `'Others'` add an option named `'No Paint'` in the second dropdown and if `car` dropdown label is not `'Ohters'` remove `'No Paint'` option from second dropdown. I am stuck in adding and removing the dropdown options dynamially. Can anyone please guide, below is my code. Thanks

```
    Car: <p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" [filter]="true"></p-dropdown>

    <p-dropdown [options]="paints" [(ngModel)]="selectedPaint" [filter]="true"></p-dropdown>

    constructor() {
            this.cars= [
                {name: 'AA', code: 'aa'},
                {name: 'BB', code: 'bb'},
                {name: 'CC', code: 'cc'},
                {name: 'DD', code: 'dd'},
                {name: 'Others', code: 'others'}
            ];

this.paints= [
                {name: 'XX', code: 'xx'},
                {name: 'YY', code: yyb'},
                {name: 'ZZ', code: 'zz'}
            ];
```

Model: DropDownOptions.ts

```
export class DropDownOptions {
label: string;
value: string
}
```

I did try `this.cars.push(new DropDownOptions('Others', 'others'))` but this is adding 'Others' option as many times as I change dropdown values.

Comment: Please create stackblitz link

Comment: @Justcode I am so sorry, its blocked in my organization.

Comment: try any of the the online creator, try codpen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite simple. Add on first p-dropdown (car) event `(onChange)`

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cars" 
(onChange)="checkIfOther($event)" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedCar" 
[filter]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

.ts:

```
checkIfOther(event){
if(event.value.code === 'others'){
this.paints.find(paint => paint.code == 'No Paint') === undefined ? this.paints.push({name:'No paint', code: 'No Paint'}) : null;
}
else{
let idx = this.paints.findIndex(paint => paint.code == 'No Paint';
idx != undefined ? this.paints.slice(idx,1) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using ES6 as below:

```
if(event.value.code === 'others'){
this.paints.find(paint => paint.code == 'No Paint') === undefined ? this.paints.push({name:'No paint', code: 'No Paint'}) : null;
}
else{
this.paints = this.paints.filter(e => e !== 'Others') //remove 'Others'
}
```